# 2D matrix traverse - optimal path memorization

Tags: c, matrix, stack, traversal

I have a function that is used to find the optimal path in a 2D matrix (structure of integers, value and sum) but it doesn't memorize optimal values, it only return the minimum cost of the traversal once it gets down to the bottom of the matrix. We're supposed to use the stack to somehow memorize these optimal values, but I unfortunately have no clue how to do that. It is a recursive algorithm so that makes it a bit hard to analyze. Values are filled with pseudo-randoms (1 to 10) and sum is initialized to `INT_MAX`.  This seems to be a bit similar to a ternary tree.

Stack function prototypes are:

```
stack_t stack_new(); // already done in main
void stack_delete(stack_t stack); // -||-
void stack_push(stack_t stack, stack_element_t elem);
stack_element_t stack_pop(stack_t stack);
stack_element_t stack_top(stack_t stack);
int stack_is_empty(stack_t stack);

/* recursively seeks the optimal path in a 2D matrix */

void traverse(struct path **matrix, unsigned row, unsigned col, int path_cost, int *min_cost, int *cnt, stack_t stack, FILE *f)
{
    char buffer[16];
    path_cost += matrix[row][col].value;
    matrix[row][col].sum = path_cost;
    (*cnt)++; // counting calls
    fprintf(f, "call_counter: %d, min_cost: %s, path_cost: %d, value: %d, sum: %d\n", *cnt, *min_cost == INT_MAX ? "Inf" : itoa(*min_cost, buffer, 10), path_cost, matrix[row][col].value, matrix[row][col].sum); // logging
    if(matrix[row][col].sum > *min_cost) // if we've been here before and it wasn't as costly, return
    {
        return;
    }
    if(row == MATRIX_ROW - 1) // if we're at the bottom of the matrix
    {
        if(path_cost < *min_cost)
        {
            *min_cost = path_cost;
        }
        return;
    }
    if (col < MATRIX_COL - 1) // go down and right
        traverse(matrix, row + 1, col + 1, path_cost, min_cost, cnt, stack, f);

    traverse(matrix, row + 1, col, path_cost, min_cost, cnt, stack, f); // go down

    if (col > 0) // go down and left
        traverse(matrix, row + 1, col - 1, path_cost, min_cost, cnt, stack, f);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use find the path using two stacks .
One will be the temporary stack , while the other being **ANSWER** stack .

What the basic idea will be that as you make a move , you push the direction , in which you went ,into the stack .Also after the "Function call ()" for that particular move ,you pop() that direction .Then , The step when you reach the bottom ,and  if the following condition is true :

```
if(path_cost < *min_cost)
{
  *min_cost = path_cost;
}
```

you empty the Answer stack , and copy the contents of Temporary stack into it.

```
stack answer ;
stack temporary;

/* recursively seeks the optimal path in a 2D matrix */



void traverse(struct path **matrix, unsigned row, unsigned col, int path_cost, int *min_cost, int *cnt, stack_t stack, FILE *f)
{
    char buffer[16];
    path_cost += matrix[row][col].value;
    matrix[row][col].sum = path_cost;
    (*cnt)++; // counting calls
    fprintf(f, "call_counter: %d, min_cost: %s, path_cost: %d, value: %d, sum: %d\n", *cnt, *min_cost == INT_MAX ? "Inf" : itoa(*min_cost, buffer, 10), path_cost, matrix[row][col].value, matrix[row][col].sum); // logging
    if(matrix[row][col].sum > *min_cost) // if we've been here before and it wasn't as costly, return
    {
        return;
    }
    if(row == MATRIX_ROW - 1) // if we're at the bottom of the matrix
    {
        if(path_cost < *min_cost)
        {
            *min_cost = path_cost;
            
            /*
            
            just empyty teh Answer stack here;
            then copy the Temp stack into answer stack
            
            */
            
        }
        return;
    }
    
    // 1 for (row +1 ,col +1 )
    // 2 for (row +1 ,col )
    // 3 for (row +1 ,col -1 )
    
    if (col < MATRIX_COL - 1) // go down and right
    {
        temporary.push(1);
        traverse(matrix, row + 1, col + 1, path_cost, min_cost, cnt, stack, f);
        temporary.pop(1);
    }
    
    temporary.push(2);  
    traverse(matrix, row + 1, col, path_cost, min_cost, cnt, stack, f); // go down
    temporary.pop(2);
    
    if (col > 0) // go down and left
    {
        temporary.push(3);      
       traverse(matrix, row + 1, col - 1, path_cost, min_cost, cnt, stack, f);
       temporary.pop(3);
    }
}
```

***EDIT:***

pop() and push() from temporary stack. The answer stack is updated each time you find a "potential" solution .Also i didnt have time to do the parameter passing .The temprary stack "MUST" be local .Use Answer stack as you want .

Comment: I'm not sure I follow this - I am supposed to pop which stack when I make a move? Should they be globally visible like you intended or not? What about the one I am already passing to the function? Please clarify.

Comment: Since you are Iterating over all possible solutions , what we try to do is keep a stack of the elements which we "encountered" in our current trace of recursive calls.

Comment: Push() - signifies that current element is recorded in our path .And if it is constituent of Optimal path ,it will remain in that stack ,untill the call is over .

Comment: Pop() - After the function call finishes ,the current direction ,if required( i.e. optimal ), will have been recorded in answer stack on reaching the bottom .Now if we dont pop() the just visited direction,instead push() other direciton too ,it will technicaly signify that in single step ,we took 2 paths ,which i hope u understand is wrong !

Comment: Also comment me a alink to your final solution whic h you implemented ,if you still face problem .

Comment: This is how it looks so far - http://pastebin.com/B4S9X79B On a side note, it seems you are treating "stack" as class (you are using function members), C doesn't have those.